# Changing app to use a Tab Bar controller

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm creating my first iPhone application (using XCode 4), and I initially created the project using the Navigation based application template. I've since decided that I want the UI to have a Tab Bar down the bottom with a Navigation Bar up the top, but am having difficulty changing my app to do that.

I added a new window to my app, and called it TabWindow.xib. I opened this up in Interface Builder and added a Tab Bar Controller. I then added an outlet property for the controller into AppDelegate.h as follows:-

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;
```

This was synthesized in AppDelegate.m with the following:-

```
@synthesize tabController=_tabController;
```

I then changed the code in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions to the following (to switch out the old view controller with my new one):-

```
//self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
```

When I run the application, instead of seeing the Tab Bar view as expected, I see an empty window. I suspect I need to (at the very least) connect to the tabController outlet I created above, but I can't figure out how to do this. And is there anything else I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the connection to the app delegate in interface builder. To do this, add an "Object" from the Object library and change its class to your app delegate. Then add the connections in the connections inspector.

Also, in your applications info plist file, you might have to set "Main nib file base name" to the new xib name.

Comment: I've done as you suggested, and have connected the tabController and window outlets, and changed the Main nib file base name in the plist file, but I'm still seeing an empty window. One thing I did note is that the Files owner is connected to the App Delegate in the original MainWindow.xib, but not in my new TabWindow.xib, but I can't figure out how to set it. If I ctrl+drag from the File's Owner object to the App Delegate one, I don't get the opportunity to connect to an outlet.

Comment: After adding the "Object" from the Object library, did you set the class on the "Object"? You have to do this from the identity inspector. The Custom Class field there should be set to your app delegate class.

Once that is done, you should be able to drag connect the delegate outlet to your app delegate class Object using the connections inspector.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for not mentioning that in my previous comment.

Comment: I've got it working. I noticed that the File's Owner class was set to "NSObject". I changed it to "UIApplication", and was able to file owner delegate with the ctrl+click drag mentioned above. And now when I run my app, I'm seeing the TabWindow as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Running out of thoughts here. Can you check if your File's Owner class is "UIApplication" in its identity inspector.